# Show $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{f(x) < t} \varphi(x) \text{d}x \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}_t )$ if $\varphi \in C^\infty_0$, $\nabla f \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $f \in C^\infty(X)$ is real-valued, with the property that $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in X$. For any $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(X)$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, define
$$\varphi_f(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{f(x) < t} \varphi(x) \text{d}x.$$

> I would like to show that $\varphi_f \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

This is a claim made in Chapter 7 of Friedlander's book on distributions. I am having trouble following his justification.

My attempt at a solution:

My idea is to first show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{f(x) < t} \varphi(x) \text{d}x$ is well-defined (i.e., that the derivative exists) and find it's value, with the hope this will give a clue about how to calculate the higher-order derivatives. For $h > 0$:

$$\frac{1}{h} \left(\int_{f(x) < t} \varphi(x) \text{d}x - \int_{f(x) < t + h} \varphi(x) \text{d}x \right) = \frac{1}{h} \int \mathbf{1}_{t \le f < t + h }(x) \varphi(x) \text{d}x.$$

But it's not clear to me that the right side converges to anything as $h \to 0^+$. I think maybe a change of variables (made possible by the implicit function Theorem?) is in order to make the dependence on $f$ more explicit.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you apply [the coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) with $g = \varphi / |\nabla f|$, you can at least find a nice formula for $\varphi_f$.